# Performance issues when running Android Studio Profiler: The IDE is running low on memory

Tags: android, android-studio, profiler, low-memory, android-profiler

When running Android Studio Profiler I get this message at the bottom after generating two or three "heap dumps":

```
 The IDE is running low on memory and this might affect performance. Please consider increasing available heap.
```

My PC runs really slow after getting this message even after stopping the profiler and the only option to restore performance is restarting Android Studio.

Why is this happening? Is there any other way to restore the performance after generating a heap dump on a project?

Answer (score 2):

Performance is improved after setting 'IDE Max Heap size' from 1280 MB(Default) to 2048 MB:

File --> Settings --> Appearance & Behavior  --> System Settings --> Memory Settings

Comment: I've been using Android Studio for a year and never had any problems. Now after recent latest update, I get the same issue. Even with my max heap size at maximum (4gb). Do you know what might be the reason?

Comment: I have this issue in this week with my project of company. I get 8GB RAM more and computer have 16gm RAM now.  I set 3072 GB IDE max heap size but it has same issue still.

Answer (score 0):

I just had the same issue in AS4.2 reoccurring multiple times despite as and macOS restarts. What I did to solve it: I reverted my local git change (in one file there was a change related to an annotation) - that was the last change I did before the issue started to occur.

I also turned off creating all gradle tasks in AS Preferences > Experimental > Gradle section.