# IDE is running on low memory

Tags: android-studio

Android studio running too slow Saying IDE is running on low memory

please help its a headache while IDE is running slow

how can i solve this.
Please help!!

here is screen shot of that message coming on android studio[image]

Comment: make sure to stop unnecessary services, especially your antivirus this will free up your memory

Comment: also here is a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61847110/performance-issues-when-running-android-studio-profiler-the-ide-is-running-low) but without accepted answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Android Studio is limited to 1.5 GBs of Memory, as it is usually enough to run the IDE.

However, if you have spare Memory resources, just click on the `configur` button in the pop-up, it shows you a dialog where you can change the limits of Memory for Android Studio.

If you are not spare on Memory, there is no way to solve this, as it just means your machine might be too weak to run Android Studio.

Also, if you're running Andriod Studio, make sure you are not running any other IDEs or heavy applications.

Comment: in that memory setting if i tried to increase 1920 to 2050 so why its not changing

Comment: You might need to restart Android Studio after setting is applied. And is this an example or did you actually change the memory from 1920 MBs to 2050 MBs? If so, that is a small change and is probably not very effective

Comment: i didnt give example i actually did this and also restart studio but after restarting i checked that it was same as before nothing changed

Comment: Go to Settings, and search for "Memory", find "IDE Max Heap Size", change that setting and restart the IDE. That should fix the issue